# converting python output in spread sheet format

Tags: python

here, i need to get two values from user and save that output in a spread sheet format.
the mcve of my code is :

```
while True:
    a=input('enter the string')
    print(a)
    b=input('enter the number')
    print(b)
```

the sample output is:

```
enter the stringa
a
enter the number2
2
enter the stringb
b
enter the number4
4
enter the string
```

I need to assign each integer value to the respective string in an spreadsheet

Comment: I guess we will need more information about your output format. Are you talking about CSV?

Comment: no, not in csv file. i need to convert in xlwt

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you're looking for a library to write an excel file [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) is a possible option.

Comment: You mean writing an `xls` format file using [xlwt](https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) python library?

Comment: yes, but i cant import those libraries

Comment: Is there any library you can use?

Comment: now i installed the xlsxwriter. can you guide me how to write a code.or you can guide me to create a csv file

Answer (score 2):

Try using openpyxl to save the outputs in excel sheet

```
from openpyxl import Workbook


book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active
a = input('enter the string')
print(a)
b = input('enter the number')
print(b)
sheet['A1'] = a
sheet['B1'] = b



book.save("test.xlsx")
```

Comment: this code creates the spreadsheet and stores only first two value.But i need to store the entire user input without over writing it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `xlsxwriter` it's pretty simple:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

rowCount = 0
while <some condition>:
    a=input('Enter the string: ')
    print(a)
    b=input('Enter the number: ')
    print(b)

    worksheet.write_row(rowCount, 0, (a,b))
    rowCount += 1

workbook.close()
```

This will create a workbook with a worksheet, then it will ask the user to enter the string and the associated value. It will then store the values in the workbook, increasing the row at each loop.